# Symfony 6 RequestStack Session not getting value

Tags: symfony

Until now I worked with Symfony 5.2. Now I installed new environment with Symfony 6.

Now the Session engine is changed, **RequestStack** should use now.
I setup as https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html.

It looks like, value is saving but not loading again (session folder contains corresponding files).

**Initial route:**

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/",
 *     name="home",
 *     methods={"GET","POST"}
 * )
 *
 * @param RequestStack $requestStack
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(RequestStack $requestStack): Response
{
    $session = $requestStack->getSession();
    $session->set('test','test');

    return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', []);
}
```

**Test route:**

```
    /**
 * @Route(
 *     "/test",
 *     name="test",
 *     methods={"GET","POST"}
 * )
 * @param RequestStack $requestStack
 * @return Response
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function test(RequestStack $requestStack): Response
{
    $session = $requestStack->getSession();
    echo "Test: ".$session->get('test','err');  // <== I get 'err'

    return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', []);
}
```

- Every main page refresh, new session file will created.
- In browser i don't see corresponding session hash
- In JavaScript **document.cookie = "MyCookie";** works

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood your link.  There used to be a SessionInterface that allowed you to inject a session directly into a service.  [That interface has gone away](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation) and is replaced with the RequestStack.  However for controller actions you still inject just the request from which you can get the session with $request->getSession().  No need to change controller code.  By the way, your 'Initial Route' is confusing your changed the name of the $request variable but not the type.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, I tried your 'Initial Route' code in a fresh 6.0 project and it all seemed to work as expected.  The session id cookie was sent and the value set.  Refreshing did not change the value of the id cookie.

Comment: Thx for answer. I changed initial route, but I still cannot read session because browser don't set uid as cookie. I don't see the problem.

Comment: When 6.0 was released, I made a fresh project just to test these sorts of things out.  [Here is the controller I used](https://github.com/cerad/s6bundle/blob/master/src/Controller/DefaultController.php).  Feel free to clone the repo and try it yourself.  I suspect you have something else going on.

Comment: There must be any missconfiguration on system, I think. I made also new simple 6.0 project on other server and it works. So I copied whole package to desired environment and there it don't works anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: Since update Synfony and PHP, access to resources by domain name needs to have certificate. After installing lets encrypt it works (also for in-house-acces-only).