# Set session variable but can't access it from another controller

Tags: symfony, session

I'm trying to set a session variable when I log in, which seems to work, but I can't get this variable in another function of another controller.

```
(SecurityController.php)

public function login(RequestStack $requestStack): Response
{
    //$session = $requestStack->getSession();
    $session = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('uuid_user', $user->getUuid());

    $this->logger->info($session->get('uuid_user')); //I can access this and it works here
}


(CityController.php)

public function getCity(RequestStack $requestStack): Response
{
    //$session = $requestStack->getSession();
    $session = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
    $uuidUser = $session->get('uuid_user');
    
    $this->logger->info($uuidUser); //I can't access that here, it just returns null
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the docs really that confusing?  This is the second [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380460/symfony-6-requeststack-session-not-getting-value?noredirect=1#comment124439190_70380460) in which the poster thought they needed to use the RequestStack inside of a controller.  Just inject the Request as usual and pull the session from that.  The provided link includes a simple test case you can try.  If I had to guess the problem is probably more with the security configuration than sessions.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, the session changes (look at your PHPSESSID cookie). You probably set the uuid_user on the old session and not the new one.

Set the uuid_user on onAuthenticationSuccess in your Authenticator (in folder src/Security) should work